# im having a React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies:

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

problem is probably on useEffect where the console spits out

> src\components\Pagination\PaginaionRaw.jsx
> Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'onPaginationChange' and 'showPerPage'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'onPaginationChange' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-dep

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import PaginationCSS from "./pagination.module.css";
import { PreviousButton, NextButton } from "./button";

const PaginationRaw = ({ showPerPage, onPaginationChange, total }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const [totalPage] = useState(Math.ceil(total / showPerPage));
   

  useEffect(() => {
    const value = showPerPage * currentPage;
    onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value);
  }, [currentPage]);

  const changePage = (type) => {
    //code
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    if (type === "prev") {
      setCounter(currentPage - 1);
    } else if (type === "next") {
      setCounter(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className={PaginationCSS["pagination-container"]}>
        <PreviousButton currentPage={currentPage} changePage={changePage} />
        <ul className={PaginationCSS["pagination-list"]}>
          {new Array(totalPage).fill("").map((element, index) => (
            <li
              key={index + 1}
              className={PaginationCSS["pagination-page-item"]}
            >
              <a
                onClick={() => setCounter(index + 1)}
                href="# "
                className={
                  index + 1 === currentPage
                    ? `${PaginationCSS["pagination-page-activeLink"]}`
                    : `${PaginationCSS["pagination-page-link"]}`
                }
              >
                {index + 1}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <NextButton
          currentPage={currentPage}
          changePage={changePage}
          totalPage={totalPage}
        ></NextButton>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PaginationRaw;
```

Comment: When you include those values in the dependency array, does anything fail?

Comment: There is a function call, and as the error nicely put, we can include it in dep's array and wrap the function in a useCallback the other one seems a primitive value ...

Comment: @KcH  `useCallback` won't gain you anything here, as the callback is inside the `useEffect`, but yes, putting all deps that's used inside the `useEffect` as the answer from Polina should do it.

Comment: Thanks @Keith ... but the reference would always be different so I thought it would go into useCallback 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert onPaginationChange and showPerPage into the useEffect dependencies array (right after currentPage). It is needed bacause they come from component props, so hook will be redefined if these props will be changed.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const value = showPerPage * currentPage;
        onPaginationChange(value - showPerPage, value);
      }, [currentPage, onPaginationChange, showPerPage]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I undstood what had happen because of you